# Would it make sense to build a wiki of generic accessories?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

Many very useful - and recommendable - inexpensive accessories are offered under dozens of brand names each - eg lens adapters, cable releases, tripod parts and backpacks.

Would it make sense to build a community wiki page or set of pages assigning a synthetic name (eg md-to-m43-adapter-style-no-5) to each "phenotype", and listing their properties and the typical brands these are sold under?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how maintainable such a listing would be and it sounds a bit like product recommendations which aren't really what a Q/A site is ideal for.  A lot of off brand stuff can come and go frequently too.  I wouldn't give it a hard thumbs down if the community wanted to try it, but I don't expect it would work out very well.

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion seems like a giant product catalog. It kind of already exists elsewhere ([Camera Wiki](http://camera-wiki.org/), [Camerapedia](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Camerapedia)). It would probably be better to ask a specific question about a problem that a class of products have been designed to solve. Then you can include the desired information in an answer, like this:

- [What macro techniques offer an alternative to expensive optics?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9341/75526)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you call a phenotype here. But yes, we could definitely have  a wiki on accessories, that tells what their purpose(s) is(are), how to use them, how to recognize the good ones, or what price bracket to expect for something that works adequately.

Comment: My intended meaning was "obviously made on the same tooling". Especially interesting with adapters vs the way they fit third party lenses :)

Comment: @rackandboneman What does "made on the same tooling" mean?

Comment: Phenotype is borrowed from biology. A common exercise in intro courses is to [analyze the phenotype of common objects](http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/bcr.02.2011.3869). Some features, such as the number of screws used to attach the mount ring, aren't generally useful for photography. (But might be useful to those who like to modify equipment.)

Comment: It IS useful info when modifying an off-the-shelf item is a solution. Eg if it is about mounting something with a modified version of a lens mount - think ix-Nikkor or Olympus-OM-AF lenses, not all adapters will work equally, some will need modification, some won't be modified easily.